Google Drive's virtual disk sometimes has weird permissions that make it inaccessible
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 through WSL 2, and I have Google Drive through Windows 11 which creates a virtual disk on G:. I have the drive mounted in WSL at /mnt/g. Sometimes, I think because of the network disconnecting when the computer sleeps, /mnt/g ends up in a weird state where it seems to exist and yet not exist at the same time. This is the output of ls -al /mnt:
ls: cannot access '/mnt/g': No such device
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x  8 root    root    4.0K Nov 21 21:13 ./
drwxr-xr-x 27 root    root    4.0K Dec  2 08:52 ../
drwxr-xr-x  1 me      me      4.0K Dec  1 08:40 c/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4.0K Nov 21 21:13 d/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4.0K Jun  2  2023 f/
d?????????  ? ?       ?          ?            ? g/
drwxrwxrwt  2 root    root      60 Dec  2 08:52 wsl/
drwxrwxrwt  7 root    root     300 Dec  5 06:23 wslg/

I realize I'm supposed to re-mount the drive if this happens. I have a script called ezmount that simplifies the process. Here are the contents:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
DRIVE_LETTER="$1"

if [[ ! "$DRIVE_LETTER" ]]; then
    echo Please enter a drive letter.
    exit 1
fi

mount_path="/mnt/${DRIVE_LETTER,,}"

if [[ ! -e "$mount_path" ]]; then
    sudo mkdir "$mount_path"
    
    if [[ "$?" ]]; then
        echo Something went wrong in trying to create the directory "$mount_path".
        exit 1
    fi
fi

sudo mount -t drvfs "${DRIVE_LETTER^^}:" "$mount_path" -o "uid=$(id -u $USER),gid=$(id -g $USER),metadata"

When the script gets to the line sudo mkdir "$mount_path", the response is mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/g’: File exists, and the script terminates without mounting. So even though checking for the existence of /mnt/g through [[ -e /mnt/g ]] returns false, Ubuntu still claims the path exists. In general, I want the script to create the mount path if it doesn't exist in case a new drive is added, but in this scenario I want it to realize the path already exists and re-mount it. I don't want to have to type the long mount command myself, that's why I wrote the script. Is there some command I should use other than -e that would work in this scenario?
